# Linear layout above tab activity

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-xml

I need to place a linear layout with edit text and custom toggle switch above the tabbed activity.

[image]

Any idea how to go about it placing the tabs below the linear layout

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

                <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Wassup!"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#22000000"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```